# How can I have Org use `sidewaysfigure` in LaTeX export?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-export

I am writing an Org document with some large figures (images) which I would like to place on a separate page in landscape orientation when exporting to LaTeX.  In LaTeX I can achieve what I want by using `\begin{sidewaysfigure}`.  What is the easiest way to get Org to do this?

Google turns up [this documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-specific-attributes.html), which mentions sideways tables but not sideways figures AFAICT, and [this patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-04/msg00185.html), which should add support for sideways figures, but I don't think it has been merged into the version I installed from the Org-mode ELPA repository.  (`M-x org-version` displays `Org-mode version 8.2.9 (8.2.9-elpaplus @ […] ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20141012/`).

Is there an easy way to get this behavior with my current version of Org?

(Edited to add: It looks like the patch above has been merged into the bleeding-edge Org snapshot, so perhaps I should just install that.  However, I would still be interested to know if there is a way to get this functionality using the current stable release of Org from October 2014).

Comment: Doesn't it work if you just add `\begin{sidewaysfigure}`?

Comment: Not as well as I would like.  If I just add `#+LATEX: \begin{sidewaysfigure}` and `#+LATEX: \end{sidewaysfigure}` before and after, I get a `figure` environment within a `sidewaysfigure`, which does not render properly.  I could just drop down to LaTeX for the whole thing, of course, but I'd like to retain Org's ability to export to different formats as well if possible.

Comment: For the time being I've installed the latest Org revision from Git, which works very well for this, although it seems to have bugs in other areas (understandably).  If worst comes to worst I guess I can apply the `:float sideways` patch to the stable version locally.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the `sidewaysfigure` environment needs to *replace* the `figure` environment? Sounds like a job for exporti hooks. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a current `org` version (at least 8.2.10, which is the one
currently shipped with Emacs), you can achieve what you want by simply using
`#+begin_sidewaysfigure` instead of `#+begin_figure`.

Try:

```
(with-temp-buffer (insert
"#+LATEX_HEADER: \\usepackage{rotating}
#+NAME: sideway
#+CAPTION: test
#+begin_sidewaysfigure
[[file:test.png]]
#+end_sidewaysfigure")
(org-mode)
(org-latex-export-as-latex nil nil nil t))
```

Result:

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\caption{\label{sideway}test}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{test.png}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

For html you could get:

```
<div class="sidewaysfigure">

<div class="figure">
<p><img src="test.png" alt="test.png" />
</p>
</div>

</div>
```

which is then for you to fix via css or whatnot.

Comment: It seems this answer is saying to use a recent org version and use `#+begin_sidewaysfigure` instead of `#+begin_figure`. But it doesn't actually *say* that. Could you clarify?

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I've since switched to using the most recent Org which has a specific option for sideways floats, but this will be very useful if I need other miscellaneous kinds of LaTeX environments in future.